# htaccess rewrite pass two variables or one depending if both are available?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to pass first directory as a variable and subdirectory as another variable.

It works when for urls with both directories (/something/something2) but I get an error 404 when I try with only one (/something).

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+) /posts/?category2=$1&category2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

How can I pass only category1 when category2 isn't available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few solutions:

Multiple rules (easier to understand but a bit slower):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /posts/?category2=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) /posts/?category2=$1&category2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? /posts/?category2=$1&category2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Here the second part of URL (/something2) is optional. Please note -- $2 was changed to $3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? /posts/?category2=$1&category2=$3 [L,QSA]
```