# Redirect with .htaccess with one, two OR three variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I make clean URL's with one, two OR three variables?

I want domain.com/mypage to direct to index.php?page=mypage and
domain.com/mypage/myproduct to redirect to index.php?page=mypage&var2=myproduct and domain.com/mypage/myproduct/detail to redirect to index.php?page=mypage&var2=myproduct&var3=detail. So some pages have three variables, others have only one or two.

This is the .htaccess I'm using (it includes a part I found at [htaccess rewrite pass two variables or one depending if both are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869006/htaccess-rewrite-pass-two-variables-or-one-depending-if-both-are-available)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? index.php?page=$1&var1=$3 [L,QSA]
```

It's working for links with one or two variables. How can I make it work for three (or more) variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just do each of them separately:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Using your .htaccess breaks everything unfortunately. Except for the homepage, all pages return a 404. For example domain.com works but domain.com/mypage gives a 404.

Comment: @Rambo if this isn't in the document root, try removing the `/` in front of `index.php?`

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. I've even expanded it to take five vars. Thanks so much!